# regular expression to get the filename from urls

Tags: c#

if i have a textbox with severals urls

rapidshare.com/files/379028801/foo.bar.HDTV.XviD-LOL.avi

rapidshare.com/files/379182651/foo.bar.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.mkv

rapidshare.com/files/379180004/foo.bar.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.part1.rar
rapidshare.com/files/379180444/foo.bar.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.part2.rar
rapidshare.com/files/379181251/foo.bar.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.part3.rar
rapidshare.com/files/379181743/foo.bar.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.part4.rar

i need a the files name and its urls

textbox2.text =

foo.bar.HDTV.XviD-LOL.avi

from here
rapidshare.com/files/379028801/foo.bar.HDTV.XviD-LOL.avi

foo.bar.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.part1.rar
from here
rapidshare.com/files/379180004/foo.bar.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.part1.rar

and so on

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could use this regex for getting the file name,

```
rapidshare.com/files/[0-9]*/(?<name>.*)$
```

The C# code would look like,

```
                string text= textbox1.Text;
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"rapidshare.com/files/[0-9]*/(?<name>.*)$");
                MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);
                if (matches.Count > 0)
                {
                    string fileName = (from Match match in matches
                                       where match.Success
                                       select match.Groups["name"].Value.Trim());
                }
```

Comment: I got
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'


then changed that part to this                 

                string fileName = Convert.ToString(from Match match in matches
                                   where match.Success
                                   select match.Groups["name"].Value);

                this.TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + fileName + Environment.NewLine;


but the textbox2 is getting this

System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match,System.String]

Comment: Hey,
Sorry for the delay, was on leave for some time :). Were you able to resolve this? You are right about the first error, in my code I was adding the result of Linq query to a method accepting IEnumerable<string>. You could do .First() at the end, or if you expect multiple url's in the textbox, then add the result of the linq query to a List directly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, can't ya just get the string that follows the last / ?

Just get the substring with the beginning "LastIndexOf("/") + 1"  and you'll have it, skipping all the regex stuff. It's a single-line solution and it's quicker!

It's something like that:

> String filename = ulr.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);

Cheers,

vloo

Comment: And if you are doing that in the C# code you don't need to escape the '/', so you can replace "\ /" with '/'.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it

```
String flnam = Regex.Match("rapidshare.com/files/379028801/Fringe.S02E19.HDTV.XviD-LOL.avi",
                @".*\/([^/]*)$").Groups[1].Value.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(flnam);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to search for something like this regex and replace it with "":

```
rapidshare.com/files/[0-9]*/
```

For example, in JavaScript:

```
var fileName = fullUrl.replace(/rapidshare.com\/files\/[0-9]*\//, "");
```

Note that the `\/` escapes the `/` which would, in JavaScript, otherwise end the regular expression.